# complete debugging in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using xcod 4.2 now and its not showing the complete debug information if my application crashes. i was using xcode 3.5 earlier which shows the complete crash stack.

Is there any option to activate this option please update me?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend this setting in the Behaviors tab of Xcode preferences:
[image: Screenshot of Behaviors tab]. Create a new tab in your workspace window and rename it "Console" by double-clicking on its title.

Now when a run of your application starts, the debugger view will automatically display.

Answer (score 1):

It's displayed in the console.  There's a toggle at the top (near the organizer icon) to display the console, variables, or both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the call stack in the console . . . well you can't, it seems, but you can set a break point for all exceptions by opening the breakpoints navigator and hitting the plus button then selecing exception breakpoint.

It's not great but it should help.

Comment: I have found the call stack is always printed to the console when an application crashes, just the console is not always open.